# WPF Textblock as terminal window. Do I need to set a limit?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I am writing a new WPF control application from a scratch based on a winForm version. The control will monitor a machine over serial. Within the control I want to have a text window that will monitor the input data coming from the machine.

For this I have a TextBlock  control. My concern is that as this runs constantly that the TextBlock will might cause memory issues as the stored data grows. The control can run for months without restart.

I haven't had any search luck on limiting TextBlock memory and handling of old information.

Is there something I should do to keep the block from infinitely storing data and causing problems down the line? Or is there a better control to display and monitor incoming data from the machine?

I havent written the code for this yet as I want to start it right. However, when I did this with winform I used a TextBox. There I had an event handler detect incoming data and use stringbuilder to

```
textbox.AppendText(Environment.newline + string)
```

the received data to the window. I thought TextBlock might be a better way to go this round.

Comment: When you wrote a test program to fill a `TextBlock` with as much text as you could until either the program crashed or it no longer was responsive enough to meet your requirements, what happened? How much text were you able to put into the control? Is that enough text to accommodate your expected amount of text, with some margin? Do you have a fallback plan for how to handle the situation where in the real world, you still get more text than you expected? What? You say that you never did any such test? I guess you have some work to do before you can post a meaningful question here then!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder` to create a `string` that you then set the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` to. Any old `Text` value will then be eligible for garbage collection. There is no way and there should be no reason to "limiting TextBlock memory and handling of old information".

> Or is there a better control to display and monitor incoming data from the machine?

Whether you use a `TextBlock` or a `TextBox` shouldn't really matter as far as memory and performance are concerned. If you require the text to be selected, a `TextBox` is a better choice. Otherwise, you should choose a `TextBlock`. There is no more lighweight way to display text in a WPF application.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. I just don't have full understanding of the garbage collector and how long it will store old information in the textblock

Comment: You don't need to, i.e. you don't know for sure when the GC collects the old value. It's nondeterministic.